# How to connect Android with SQL server database?

Tags: android, sql

I am getting problem in my application

**Here is my piece of code my activity throwing an exception "Error Connection        net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                query2(); }
        });
        }
    public void query2()
    {
    Log.i("Android"," SQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
    String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address         :198.168.0.10/tracebaledb;encrypt=fasle;user=sa;password=SqlServer2005;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "SqlServer2005";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
    Log.w("Connection","open");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from AD_Login");

    //Print the data to the console
    while(reset.next()){
    Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
                  Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2)); }
    conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: 11-24 16:44:59.455: INFO/Android(422):  SQL Connect Example.
11-24 16:44:59.455: WARN/Error connection(422): net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
11-24 16:45:00.549: DEBUG/dalvikvm(281): GC_EXPLICIT freed 196 objects / 12320 bytes in 4250ms
11-24 16:47:36.713: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: I think you can't connect to a remote database. You will have to retrieve data through a webservice.

Comment: @ yDelouis I am new in android actually haven't used it before will please guide me how to use WebService to connect android with remote SQL database......Thank you in advance

Comment: This is wrong, `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address         :198.168.0.10`, what are you trying to do?  It should look like this `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://198.168.0.10`

Comment: @Simon I have modifies my code according to your suggestions it's still trowing same exception....

Comment: You have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest?

Comment: @Simon Yes I have included that as well....Sir How can I access remote SQL server database using REST webservice? Can you tell me how to write REST webservice as I don't about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to SQL Server databse throuh webservice.

Here is the sample code to call the webservice.

```
String url              = "your_webservice_URL";

 try 
 {
    HttpPost loginHttpPost   = new HttpPost(url); 
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();          

    MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
    multipartContent.addPart("parameter1", new StringBody(value1));
    multipartContent.addPart("parameter2", new StringBody(value2));
    loginHttpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);

    HttpClient objHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = objHttpClient.execute(loginHttpPost,localContext);
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
```

Make sure you set the permission in Manifest.xml file,

You can write the webservice in php or java to get this values and connect to SQL Server

Comment: @Dennis-mathew...I want to write webservice in java but used it before and don't know how to write it if you have any sample code or example giving clear picture about it please add it in reply...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An other approach is to use a Virtual JDBC Driver that uses a three-tier architecture: your JDBC code is sent through HTTP to a remote Servlet that filters the JDBC code (configuration & security) before passing it to the SQL Server JDBC Driver. The result is sent you back through HTTP. There are some free software that use this technique. This is secure because the database is never exposed directly and you may use SSL. Just Google "Android JDBC Driver over HTTP".