# Connecting android application with .net application on server

Tags: android, .net, database-connection

I am developing the android application for entering data's in mySQL using PHP as a final year project..
But the company is using .net server and they require to build my android application to process data on their server..
Is there any feasibility to connect android with mySQL or any other DB using IIS server or directly **without using PHP** ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using webservice
[How to connect Android with SQL server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540583/how-to-connect-android-with-sql-server-database)

or try this
http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/